# Differential equation-issue

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help with this task:

Determine the constant $k$ such that the function $y$ given by the following differential equation: $$\frac {dy}{dx}-y=xe^{kx}$$

satisfies $\lim_{x\to \infty} y(x)=0$ and $y(0)=−0.8.$

I've solved the differential equation and end up with:
$$y= Ce^x + \frac{kx(e^{kx})}{(k-1)^2}-\frac{x(e^{kx})}{(k-1)^2}-\frac{e^{kx}}{(k-1)^2}$$

Using the initial condition:
$$-0.8=C-\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}$$

What I *do not* quite understand is how to use the information about the limit when $x$ approach infinity being zero. I just end up with something like *infinity - infinity* etc. which doesn't help.

Comment: The image is too small to read, even when magnified it's too blurry. It seems odd your solution has three terms all with the same denominator though...

Comment: @Migr: You have a statement in your problem that refers to a limit. What is that?

Comment: Anyone able to help? Everything should be there now.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $dy/dx + y ...$ for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the general solution that you found:
\begin{align*}
 y = C e^x +\frac{e^{kx}\big(kx-x-1)}{(k-1)^2}
\end{align*}
is correct.

Now, you notice that you are told that $\lim_{x\to\infty} y(x) = 0$; this means that your solution decays with this time.  The only way this is possible is to have $C=0$ (because $Ce^x$ will blow up as $x\to\infty$) and to also have $k <0$ so that $e^{kx}$ will be a decaying function. Using those two facts ($C=0$ and $k<0$), solve for $k$ in the expression 
\begin{align*}
-0.8 = \underbrace{C}_{=0}-\frac{1}{(k-1)^2}
\end{align*} and obtain
\begin{align*}
k = 1\pm \sqrt{1/.8}.
\end{align*}

Since we figured that $k<0$, use $k=1-\sqrt{1/.8}\approx -0.12$.